# Python append to file opened inside a class

Tags: python, class, append

Here is my python code. I am attempting to create a class that does file 
manipulation. I used similar structure as in this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451239/extract-specific-lines-from-file-and-create-sections-of-data-in-python) but I am unable to append to a file.

add_to_file.py-----------

```
import os
import sys

class add_to_file(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.data_file = open(filename,'a')
    def __enter__(self):  # __enter__ and __exit__ are there to support
        return self       # `with self as blah` syntax
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.data_file.close()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __append__(s):
        self.data_file.write(s)
    __append__("PQR")

add_to_file("Junk")
```

---

Result-------------------

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_to_file.py", line 4, in <module>
    class add_to_file(object):
  File "add_to_file.py", line 15, in add_to_file
    __append__("PQR")
  File "add_to_file.py", line 14, in __append__
    self.data_file.write(s)
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Does def __append__(self, s) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what exactly you're trying to accomplish — it looks sort of like a context manager class. I renamed `__append__()` to `append()` because methods that start and end with double underscores should only be defined by the language and I renamed your class from `add_to_file` to `AddToFile` in accordance with [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
import os
import sys

class AddToFile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.data_file = open(filename,'a')
    def __enter__(self):  # __enter__ and __exit__ are there to support
        return self       # `with self as blah` syntax
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.data_file.close()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def append(self, s):
        self.data_file.write(s)


with AddToFile("Junk") as atf:
    atf.append("PQR")

with open("Junk") as file:
    print(file.read())  # --> PQR
```

Comment: Thank you, that works fine. Still trying to figure out some basics__beginer_newbie

Comment: The most important things that were wrong were calling the `append()` method in the class definition itself and not having an initial `self` argument in its  definition.

Answer (score 2):

Change `def __append__(s):` to `def __append__(self, s):`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_to_file.py", line 4, in <module>
    class add_to_file(object):
  File "add_to_file.py", line 15, in add_to_file
    __append__("Junk","PQR")
  File "add_to_file.py", line 14, in __append__
    self.data_file.write(s)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'data_file'